# When is AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification triggered?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, core-audio

Quoted from Xcode doc,

> AVAudioSessionSilenceSecondaryAudioHintNotification Posted on the main
>   thread when the primary audio from other applications starts and
>   stops.
>
> Subscribe to this notification to ensure that your app is notified
>   when optional secondary audio muting should begin or end.

However, when my app's audio is playing, and I press the remote-control to start playing music from the Music app. This notification is not triggered in my observer callback. I believe the registration was successful.

Am I having the wrong expectation? Is it supposed to be triggered in a different scenario? Any examples?

Comment: did u find any solution i'm facing the same problem

Comment: Nope. But now I suspect that "secondary Audio" may not mean what I assumed. It might not be "audio from another app" but my app's audio routed to a secondary output device. I'm not sure, just a theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your AVAudioSession Category to **AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient**, then your app will allow background apps (such as music or podcasts) to play.  If you set it to **AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient** then it will not accept background music

You can do it like this:

```
NSError *categoryError = nil;
if ([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&categoryError]) {
    printf("Setting AVAudioSession CategoryAmbient Succeeded\n");
} else {
    printf("Setting AVAudioSession CategoryAmbient Failed\n");
}
```

Check out [Audio Session Categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you! Then this is not as useful as I imagined. Because user can trigger the remote-control under any categories, it has been a pain in the neck to detect other app stealing an exclusive audio session. I had expected that this was the cure, but god I was wrong! There are SoloAmbient and PlayAndRecord, under which this callback will never get triggered.